# Timing of using both a JQuery and an ASP.NET OnSelectedIndexChanged event handler

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to do something a little specific.  My idea was to try and pop up a modal dialog box using JQuery when a user changes the value of a dropdownlist.  The user should then select 'continue' or 'cancel'. I want the results of that pick to determine whether I run the ASP.NET postback event.  Right now the modal dialog pops up, but then immediately vanishes as the ASP.NET page does an `AutoPostBack` and wipes out the modal box.

What is a good/elegant way to solve my dillema?  Is there a way to have ASP.NET wait for the results or do I need some sort of hidden button to handle initiate the postback later?

Thanks for the help!

```
<asp:Content ID="MainContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content" runat="Server">
    <asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="smpProxy" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/JQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/JQuery/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js" />
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function CheckConfirmation() {
                    $('#divConfirmChange').dialog("open");
                    return false;
                }

                function pageLoad() {
                    $("#divConfirmChange").dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        resizable: false,
                        height: 158,
                        modal: true
                    });
                }
            </script>
```

Then here's my **dropdown list** further down

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlApprovalStatus" onChange="javascript:CheckConfirmation();" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProgram_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropdown lists set to autopostback can be tricky to deal with especially when it is inside of an update panel.  You need to override the postback from the page request manager.  The example below uses the default javaScript confirm but I would recommend the [jQuery Alert Dialogs plugin](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/) if you don't like the standard browser confirm as the regular jQuery dialogs will not stop the postback from firing without some extra hooks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_initializeRequest(initializeRequest);

    function initializeRequest(sender, args) {
        var el = args.get_postBackElement().id;
        if (el == '<%=ddlApprovalStatus.ClientID %>') {
            if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) {
                args.set_cancel(true);            
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I've never had to do this before.  It looks promising, but I keep receiving an error that Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager is null.  (In fact my Sys object doesn't contain a property called WebForms when I debug)  I'm doing further research to try and resolve the issue, any tips are appreciated.  Thanks for your response!

Comment: Try putting it at the bottom of the page to resolve your error.